# Polar Rose 2D offset

Tags: c++, 2d, polar-coordinates, parametric-equations

I'm having some trouble trying to plot a polar rose with a offset C of the equation
 r(theta) = cos(k*theta) + C.
I'm trying to plot this polar rose: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#/media/File:Cartesian_to_polar.gif

The polar equation can be:
r(theta) = cos(k * theta) 

or

r(theta) = sin(k * theta)

The equation of the polar rose I want to draw is: 
r(theta) = 2 + sin(6 * theta)

Ok, and the parametric equations will be:
x = C + sin(k * theta) * cos(theta)
y = C + sin(k * theta) * sin(theta)

In my Canvas(drawing area), my origin is not at the center of the screen, so I need to translate the rose to it. Ok, no big deal. Another point is that I need to scale the rose for it to be visible or it will be too small, but still no problem, this explains the: 100*. Here is my code, it is on C++ btw:

```
for ( float t = 0; t < PI_2; t+= 0.01 )
{
    r = Origin.get_x() + 100*(2+(sin(6*t) * cos(t)));
    h = Origin.get_y() + 100*(2+(sin(6*t) * sin(t)));
    point(r,h);
}
```

I know that I'm doing it wrong, because when I add the +2 which should be the C constant is not working the way I want to, It's just translating more and drawing a polar rose without an offset. How do I prevent the "extra translation" and draw it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x = r cos(theta)`, `y = r sin(theta)` so your parametric equations should be `x(theta) = C * cos(theta) + sin(k*theta) * cos(theta)` and `y(theta) = C * sin(theta) + sin(k*theta) * sin(theta)`. You just forgot to multiply `C` by `cos(theta)` and by `sin(theta)` respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much! :D
Sorry but i have not enough reputation to vote up your answer, is there a way to put it as "correct answer?"